# store count in table or query on demand

Tags: postgresql

I want to be able to get the number of items a book has, there is a book table and item table, one to many relationships.

please consider two ,

1. every author has huge number(millions) of items,
2. or every author has less than millions of items

which approach is better:

1. create an trigger that updates the item count col in author table once insertion occurred in item table;

   1. faster query; few author page is visited millions of times per day and we don't have to query the count every time it is visited.
   2. more space
2. simply query the count with a `select count(items)` or `view`

   1. slower query
   2. less space

postgresql has cache i believe, so im looking at 2nd now.

Comment: You say you have a book table and an item table, but now want to store something in an author table.  Are you proposing to create a new table?

Comment: hi, no i meant adding a COUNT column

Comment: Try option 2 first, and if it is too slow, resort to 1.

Answer (score 1):

Storing the count in a separate column in the author table can be a good option if you want faster queries. However, this approach requires more space and can be slower when inserting new items. If you choose this approach, you can use a trigger to update the count column whenever a new item is inserted into the item table.

On the other hand, querying the count on demand can be slower but requires less space. You can use a simple `SELECT COUNT(*)` query to get the number of items for a specific author. PostgreSQL has a built-in cache that can help speed up questions that are executed frequently.

Storing the count in a separate column can be more efficient if you have millions of items per author. However, if you have fewer than millions of items per author, querying the count on demand may be a better option.

You can find more information on how to count rows in PostgreSQL tables in this Stack Overflow thread.

Here's an example of how to use a trigger to update the count column in the author table:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION update_author_item_count()
RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
BEGIN
  UPDATE author
  SET item_count = item_count + 1
  WHERE id = NEW.author_id;
  RETURN NEW;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER item_insert_trigger
AFTER INSERT ON item
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE FUNCTION update_author_item_count();
```

This trigger will update the `item_count` column in the `author` table every time a new item is inserted into the `item` table.

Here's an example of how to query the count on demand:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM item WHERE author_id = 123;
```

This query will return the number of items for the author with ID 123.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the number of rows that are going to be summed. If its thousands or millions then use the trigger. Otherwise count as you go.

Based on my experience,  I  would use the trigger. Things have a habit of growing.